# Sentiment Analysis with a Continuos Output Labels

Tags: classification, natural-language, sentiment-analysis

**Problem Setting/Context:**

I have feedback(each feedback has multiple sentences) associated with different products(you can safely assume that a feedback talks about one single product), I need to assign a continuous score for each feedback, for simplicity lets assume that this score can lie between 0 and 1(on a continuous scale) where 0 is negative, 0.5 is neutral and 1 indicates positive.

Note that none of the feedback has any labels associated with it, so I will have to build a model for any sort of predictions. This makes it challenging since assigning continuous scores to a feedback is difficult even if I were to label some data for fine tuning/ training a model to output continuous scores

**Need:**

The reason for moving towards a continuous score is to make the scoring more granular instead of just saying positive, negative or neutral additionally this also opens up options towards adding your own threshold to categorize the feedback if needed at a later point or use these scores to identify how sentiments are trending over time

**Some Ideas I have explored:**

1. One possible way is to train a model to categorize each sentence in the feedback discretely as positive(2),negative(0) or neutral(1) and then average it out to get a continuous value for a feedback.

Sample Feedback:
This Product is amazing. This product is not so good in some areas.

Then the score for the feedback would be (2+0)/2 = 1

---

2. Another possible approach which extends from the above approach could be using Prediction Probability and then taking the mean.

Sample Feedback:
This Product is amazing but under performs in some areas . The durability of the product is okay.

The scoring would be as follows:
[image]

**Question**:

1. Are there any ways to directly get continuous scoring out of models on Hugging Face or any other machine learning libraries. I already know that VADER does provide continuous score but it is dictionary based which comes with its own set of problems.
2. Please provide you inputs on the approaches above, specifically from a conceptual standpoint(machine learning concepts) do these make sense or is this incorrect? Feel free to list out any drawbacks/problems you see

*FYI:I understand that for most systems a 5 point rating system works fine and moving to a continuous scale might also raise a few questions about the interpretations of these scores but this is where we are at. Please feel free to add any suggestions you might have on this.*

Comment: Applying a sigmoid (in case of binary negative-positive classification) or a softmax (in case negative-neutral-positive) to your classifier logits should already give you a continuous value(s). I don't know if I got it right, but you don't have a single annotated example?

Comment: @Ciodar Please correct me if I am wrong but applying softmax to logits will provide me the probabilities for 3 classes but at the end of the day it will still remain a classification setup where I will have to choose a class for each of my feedback. What I would want instead is a continuous score such as 0.25 or 0.90 for my feedback. Please let me know if this is not clear in the question and I will make it explicit.

Also yea I do not have a single annotated example.

Comment: If you perform binary classification (i.e you find a pretrained model which does that in this scenario), you should already have one output, which you can bind to 0 and 1 with a softmax. Anyways, how are you currently evaluating the results or how do you think to evaluate them? Even if you perform zero-shot classification you will have to estimate your model performance against some labeled examples.

Comment: @Ciodar The idea is that if I can classify sentences correctly then the their aggregation using mean should give me a correct picture of a feedback(which contains multiple sentences). I did try pre-trained models but they do not give me what I am looking for. So then I will have to use active learning to fetch "important" sentences, label them and use them for fine tuning. Additionally I will need to create and label a validation set at sentence level and then evaluate everything on that.  I have still not come up with an efficient way on how to evaluate the overall score I give to feedback.

Comment: But again all of this only holds if the ideas I have mentioned in my question make some sense, I am looking if the community can look at the suggested options or maybe suggest something new.